# Convert Month in a date to its respective Numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have a column consist of dates

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['1 June'13' , '1 Nov'15' , '1 Dec'20']})
```

| Date |
| --- |
| 1 June'13 |
| 1 Nov'15 |
| 1 Dec'20 |

**I want to convert this date to this format-**

1-06-2013

**What I have tried-**

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
```

**what I get-**

01-Jun-2013

Is there any way to get this o/p with a small and simple  code
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: replace `%b` with `%m`: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')` ?

Comment: See the rest of the format codes here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Oops...sorry ...I was close to the answer. Thanks @anky now it really works fine. Thanks for yr reply, god bless you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with the proper date format code and using [`Series.str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) to remove the zero-padded:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y").str.lstrip('0')
#0    1-06-2013
#1    1-11-2015
#2    1-12-2020
```